# Merging two lists with python?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, combinations

I want to merge 2 lists :

```
A=['A','B','C']
B=['1','2','3']
```

I want to get a result like this :

```
C = ['A1','B2','C3']
```

Any ideas to do this in python 3. 
Thanks!

Comment: What if length of two list are not equal?

Comment: Yes it's an important point to consider!,  but in my case of study it does't matter, I dont need the elements out of range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function  within a list comprehension :

```
>>> ['{}{}'.format(i,j) for i,j in zip(A,B)]
['A1', 'B2', 'C3']
```

Or with `str.join()` :

```
>>> [''.join(i) for i in zip(A,B)]
['A1', 'B2', 'C3']
```